# How to scan through objects that are inside object. [JavaScript]

Tags: object

I am making a barcode scanner for my school project but i am stuck. I dont know how to scan through this object. I have this object with objects inside, and I need to scan through each object inside storage variable to check its barcode.

```
var storage = {
  bolts: {
  barcode: 57263144,
  price: 0.5,
  name: 'Plain Brackets',
  stock: 25,
},
brackets: {
  barcode: 13245627,
  price: 0.2,
  name: '100mm Bolts',
  stock: 2,
 },
}
```

I have a variable called barcode, and I need to test this variable if its the same like one of these. I tried using

```
for (var key in storage){
  if (storage[key].barcode === barcode){

  }
}
```

I would like the most simple way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Object.keys:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
```

Below is the example:

```
var storage = {
  "bolts": {
  barcode: 57263144,
  price: 0.5,
  name: 'Plain Brackets',
  stock: 25,
},
"brackets": {
  barcode: 13245627,
  price: 0.2,
  name: '100mm Bolts',
  stock: 2,
 }
}

var barcode = 57263144;
Object.keys(storage).forEach(function(key) {
    if(storage[key].barcode === barcode) { console.log("do something")}

});
```

A Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/spechackers/34bhthza/

Comment: Thank you very much, i wouldnt figure it out myself because i didnt know Object.keys was a thing. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Use the recursive function to verify if exist more nodes in the objects, example:

```
   const complexObj = {
     name: "nobody",
     address: { number: 22, moreNumbers: [1,2,3,4,5] },
     colors: ["green", "red"],
     numbersAgain: { first: 1, second: 4 }
    };

   function scanObj(obj){
    for (let i in obj) {
     /*
      *Do some verificatio, example:
      *I'd like to verify all numbers and if the numbers is greater than 3:
      */
      if(typeof obj[i] == "number" && obj[i] > 3){ console.log(obj[i]); }
                                
      if (typeof obj[i] === "object") {
       scanObj(obj[i])
      }
     }
    }

//call the method
scanObj(complexObj);
```

**Output: 22 4 5 4**